# Dropdown menu within a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to build or incorporate a dropdown menu system into an app I'm building however I need some help figureing out how it's accomplished. From my best guess I'd have to use the UIActionSheet, however it doesn't seem all that customizable. The best example I've come accross is within the AppShopper iOS application:
[image]

Drop down active: notice how it pushed the table down, it did not overlay the menu as the UIActionSheet might.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If that's the model you want to follow, looks to me like they are simply expanding a view in between the selector and the table itself.  It's not actually part of the table.

From the top down: there's the nav bar, the selector tool bar, the "menu" view", then the table view.  The menu view is initially of height 0, and expanded as necessary (pushing down the table view in the process).

Comment: +1, the menu in the screenshots is custom behaviour.  It's not a native control within cocoa-touch :-)